# How to download an Excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to download an Excel sheet to my specific location not to Download folder.

I tried below code. Then the file is download to the "Download" folder. I need to download this file to a given file path.

```
string filepath = "D:\";
string strDownloadableFilename = "Test.xlsx"
Using (MemoryStream stream = ExportExcel()){
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", strDownloadableFilename));
  stream.WriteTo(Response.OutPutStream); ;
  Response.End();
}
```

The file is download to "Download" folder.

Comment: It's up to the browser where to save the file, not the server-side code.  The server-side code has no knowledge of the client-side file system.  How is your browser configured to handle file downloads?  If it's configured to automatically save them to a common downloads folder then, well, that's what it's going to do.

Comment: To expand on David's excellent answer, consider the security risks if the server-side code *could* arbitrarily pick a download location on the client.  Big no-no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download an Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603151/download-an-excel-file)

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two things 
first of all what you want to achieve can't be done by downoad option it means we can read file and write in system memory as per our desired location but in that case No download popup will see so you have to decide if you need download popup and no desired location or vice versa.